# Calling php methods with strings

Tags: php, string, object, methods

I have two objects. Object A and B.

A has a method which returns B. And I want to call this dynamically so I use a string for calling a method inside of B like so:

```
$method = 'getB()->someMethod';
```

But if do this:

```
$a = new A();
$a->$method();
```

It doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn’t you call `$a->getB()` first to get *B*?

Comment: Why your method doesn't have `()`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot do it like that. `$method` can only contain the name of a method of `A`. Read about [**variable functions**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php). You could have to variables though, e.g.

```
$method1 = 'getB';
$method2 = 'someMethod';

$a->$method1()->$method2();
```

But probably it would be better to rethink the problem, consider another structure of your code and/or having a look at design patterns.

The question is: What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: Sorry to spark up an old thread, but this question and answer applied to me. I'm thinking about creating a php api for ajax calls. Would this be the best way to allow javascript to send methods as strings to interact with an object?

Comment: You can do it like that. You might also want to have a look at [`__call`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call). I cannot tell you what's the best way though. It sounds like you want to do *remote procedure calls (RPC)*. There are already some libraries for that, so you could also have a look at those.

Comment: something i actually like about php